# Can I use netTcpBinding for WCF services hosted outside of IIS?

Tags: c#, wcf, nettcpbinding

My WCF service is being hosted as a Windows managed service, so I'm unsure of whether or not I can still use the netTcpBinding. I've tried following a couple of guides at MSDN, but for some reason my service always fails to start whenever I do the switch from basicHttpBinding. Perhaps there are additional steps that services outside of the IIS are required to undergo?

Comment: You should totally be able to do that.  Can you share the pertinent config bits?

Comment: netTcpBinding is available for Windows service hosted endpoints. Can you give us some more context (error messages, service definition information, etc.)

Comment: @Terry @dlev : I'm using installutil.exe to start the service which is being run outside of VS2010, so I'm not sure on how to get the exception message. Here's my app.config: http://pastebin.com/s3ibabxw

Comment: there are some errors in your config, for example baseAddress is http, and you enable httpGetEnabled for metadata, while your endpoint is HTTP. Please take an example from my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can host WCF service with netTcpBinding outside of IIS, in Windows service or even Console Application if you want to.

Here is config file sample:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
        <serviceMetadata />
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <services>
    <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior"
             name="XX.XX.Service">
      <endpoint address=""
                binding="netTcpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="BindingConfiguration"
                contract="XX.XX..IService" />
      <endpoint address="mex"
                binding="mexTcpBinding"
                contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      <host>
        <baseAddresses>
          <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8731/XXService" />
        </baseAddresses>
      </host>
    </service>
  </services>
  <bindings>
    <netTcpBinding>
      <binding
        name="BindingConfiguration">
        <security mode="None" />
      </binding>
    </netTcpBinding>
  </bindings>
</system.serviceModel>
```

**[Edit]**

Problems with your config file:

- base address is http instead of net.tcp
- metadata endpoint is mexHttpBinding instead of metTcpBinding
- security - by default windows authorization will be used, if test communication between to boxes, you might have permission problem. I suggest to start with security mode None and then adjust security when everything else works.
- you don't need to specify httpGetEnabled for service behavior
- if the port that you are going to use is already in use, you will not be able to start service

Answer (score 2):

You absolutely can, and I'd go so far as to say you should.

Here's your problem:

```
<services>
   <service name="Server.FileService" ...
      <host>
         <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8000/Test/file"/>
         </baseAddresses>
      </host>
      <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="Server.IFile" />
      <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" ...
```

The `net.tcp` address must have a `net.tcp://` prefix, not a `http://` prefix.

I don't normally use `baseAddress` so can't give advice on that. I'd remove baseAddress and instead use

```
      <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:8001/Test/file" ..
```

(note that I would also choose another port over 8000)